# What is the equivalent of C# Rijndael Key and IV in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, encryption

I have an encryption function in C# and i wish to copy it to dart:

C# (The part of code i cant reproduce in dart):

```
private RijndaelManaged myRijndael = new RijndaelManaged();
public ClsCrypto(string strPlainText)
{
string strIV = "$@A@B@_3CP$Y$T2M";

myRijndael.IV = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strIV);
myRijndael.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("$@J@Y@3NT3RPRI$3R3$OURC3PL@NNING");
byte[] originalBytes = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(strPlainText);

ICryptoTransform transform = myRijndael.CreateEncryptor();
byte[] encryptedText = transform.TransformFinalBlock(originalBytes, 0, originalB
ytes.Length);
return Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedText);
}
```

I couldn't find resources on the web, I used the "encrypt.dart" package to do this:

```
    final key = Key.fromUtf8("\$@J@Y@3NT3RPRI\$3R3\$OURC3PL@NNING");
    final iv = IV.fromUtf8("\$@A@B@_3CP\$Y\$T2M");

    final encrypter = Encrypter(AES(key));
    final encrypted = encrypter.encrypt(plainText, iv: iv);
```

but I couldn't get the same encryption.

My code and result :

```
 String strIV = "\$@J@Y@_3RP\$Y\$T3M";
    final plainText = 'CCCC-1111-CCCC-2222-CCCC-3333-CCCC';
    final key = Key.fromUtf8(String.fromCharCodes(utf8.encode("\$@J@Y@3NT3RPRI\$3R3\$OURC3PL@NNING")));
    final iv = IV.fromUtf8(String.fromCharCodes(utf8.encode(strIV)));

    final encrypter = Encrypter(AES(key));
    final encrypted = encrypter.encrypt(plainText, iv: iv);
    print("encrypted : ${encrypted.base64}");
```

result :
encrypted :

> UwQqA5DjJ7xO3POMpmyQZxINEGDM9ImcEgrC5M8pF2hiFy4CkCrbY6QBdM7EbbuR

C#:

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
namespace ConsoleApp3
{

public class ClsCrypto
{ 
private RijndaelManaged myRijndael = new RijndaelManaged();

public static void Main(){
        ClsCrypto cs = new ClsCrypto("$@J@Y@_3RP$Y$T3M");
         cs.Encrypt("CCCC-1111-CCCC-2222-CCCC-3333-CCCC");
        }
public ClsCrypto(string strIV)
{
}
public void Encrypt(string strPlainText)
{
String strIV = "$@J@Y@_3RP$Y$T3M"; //Default IV
myRijndael.IV = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strIV);
myRijndael.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("$@J@Y@3NT3RPRI$3R3$OURC3PL@NNING");
byte[] originalBytes = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(strPlainText);
ICryptoTransform transform = myRijndael.CreateEncryptor();
byte[] encryptedText = transform.TransformFinalBlock(originalBytes, 0, originalBytes.Length);
//return Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedText);
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedText));
}
}
}
```

result :

> 26CxCs5A7c7Sk5+0/hQ300vkHsCuRPXyACbrcRxyeCBWwAK9TCOLdkDHvBaLJXYH

Comment: A quick look at the [*encrypt* documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/encrypt#usage) will help: *...Default mode is SIC...* Note, another name for SIC is CTR. In addition, the Base64 encoding is missing in the Dart code. If problems persist: Post complete test data for both codes: Plaintext, key, IV and ciphertext of both codes.

Comment: @Topaco i posted both codes with results, please advise, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I already mentioned in the comment, the *encrypt* package uses SIC aka CTR as the default mode (s. [*encrypt 5.0.3*](https://pub.dev/packages/encrypt#usage), sec. *Usage - Modes of operation*), while in the C# code CBC is applied (by default).
Since the C# code is the reference, CBC must also be used in the Dart code so that both codes are compatible. This requires the following change:

```dart
final encrypter = Encrypter(AES(key, mode: AESMode.cbc));
```

With this, both codes for the same plaintext, key and IV generate the same ciphertext.

---

*Security:*
The use of a static IV is a vulnerability (better: apply a randomly generated IV).
In addition, the UTF-8 encoding of the key indicates a passphrase, which is also a vulnerability due to the generally low entropy (better: use a key derivation function in conjunction with a randomly generated salt to derive a key from the passphrase).
Salt and IV are not secret and are passed to the decrypting side along with the ciphertext (usually concatenated).
With regard to the C# code, also be aware that [`RijndaelManaged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rijndaelmanaged?view=net-8.0) is obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert of cryptography, but in dart there is the [pointy castle](https://pub.dev/packages/pointycastle)
package that is the porting of Bouncy Castle in dart.
AES algorithm is there.

Then take a look at: [encrypt](https://pub.dev/packages/encrypt)
that is a simple wrapper on poiny castle, its scope is to simplify it.

Comment: The reference to another library (library recommendations are off-topic on SO) or to the documentation should be posted as a comment and not as an answer.